# Trying to update with inner join. 2 tables(employee,contact) Joining w/common element id. Updating cellphone in contact, using fname,lname in employee

Tags: sql

I'm (3 days)new to SQL, and this is an assessment for a paid job training program, so I would be very grateful for any help.

**The assignment**:
Update Susan Shepard's cellphone to be 4383991212 using fname and lname in where clause.

So here's all my code for the 2 tables and the update query. Thanks in advance for any help or direction.

```
CREATE TABLE employee (id int, fname text (255), lname text (255), age int, hiredate date);

INSERT INTO employee (id, fname, lname, age, hiredate)
VALUES ('01', 'Alan', 'Palmer', 32, '2019-12-15');
INSERT INTO employee (id, fname, lname, age, hiredate)
VALUES ('02', 'Susan', 'Shepard', 28, '2015-07-21');
INSERT INTO employee (id, fname, lname, age, hiredate)
VALUES ('03', 'Justin', 'Ward', 43, '2017-08-24');
INSERT INTO employee (id, fname, lname, age, hiredate)
VALUES ('04', 'Alan', 'Smith', 30, '2017-06-22');
INSERT INTO employee (id, fname, lname, age, hiredate)
VALUES ('05', 'James', 'Betternot', 26, '2017-06-22');

CREATE TABLE contact (id int, cellphone text (255), homephone text (255), email text (255));

INSERT INTO contact (id, cellphone, homephone, email)
VALUES ('01', '5121325343', '5125234234', 'apalmer@yachtmail.com');
INSERT INTO contact (id, cellphone, homephone, email)
VALUES ('02', '5129739834', '5129847873', 'sshepard@yorkdevtraining.com');
INSERT INTO contact (id, cellphone, homephone, email)
VALUES ('03', '6453898502', '6459872345', 'jsward2007@yahoo.com');
INSERT INTO contact (id, cellphone, homephone, email)
VALUES ('04', '8763238756', '8763736548', 'alsmith999@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO contact (id, cellphone, homephone, email)
VALUES ('05', '8880345966', '8888567987', 'james.betternot@hotmail.com');

UPDATE contact 
SET c.cellphone ='4383991212' 
FROM contact AS c
INNER JOIN employee AS e 
ON c.id = e.id 
WHERE e.fname = 'Susan' AND e.lname = 'Shepard';
```

I've also tried this:

```
UPDATE contact 
SET contact.cellphone ='4383991212' 
FROM contact
INNER JOIN employee 
ON contact.id = employee.id 
WHERE employee.fname = 'Susan' AND employee.lname = 'Shepard';
```

**The error** I get is this:
SyntaxError: Parse error on line 2: ...one ='4383991212' FROM contact AS c I ----------------------^ Expecting 'EOF', 'COMMA', 'RPAR', 'IN', 'LIKE', 'ARROW', 'DOT', 'CARET', 'EQ', 'WHERE', 'SLASH', 'EXCLAMATION', 'MODULO', 'GT', 'LT', 'GTGT', 'LTLT', 'NOT', 'AND', 'OR', 'PLUS', 'STAR', 'END', 'WHEN', 'ELSE', 'REGEXP', 'TILDA', 'GLOB', 'NOT_LIKE', 'BARBAR', 'MINUS', 'AMPERSAND', 'BAR', 'GE', 'LE', 'EQEQ', 'EQEQEQ', 'NE', 'NEEQEQ', 'NEEQEQEQ', 'BETWEEN', 'NOT_BETWEEN', 'IS', 'DOUBLECOLON', 'OUTPUT', 'GO', 'SEMICOLON', got 'FROM'

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax for a join in the `UPDATE` statement (for Postgresql):

```
UPDATE contact AS c
SET cellphone ='4383991212'
FROM employee AS e 
WHERE c.id = e.id  AND e.fname = 'Susan' AND e.lname = 'Shepard';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=eed64b3aa1fe3e7c63864495fdecbc47).

Comment: I got this error: SyntaxError: Parse error on line 1: UPDATE contact AS c INNER JOIN emp ---------------^ Expecting 'SET', got 'AS'

Comment: @XiaHer are you sure that you are using MySql?

Comment: Sorry it's just SQL. I'll remove the tag.

Comment: @XiaHer just SQL means nothing. Each rdbms has its own sql dialect and syntax.

Comment: The database engine I'm using is most similar to PostGreSQL.

Comment: @XiaHer see my edited code.

Comment: I'm getting this error: SyntaxError: Parse error on line 1: UPDATE contact AS c SET cellphone ---------------^ Expecting 'SET', got 'AS'

Comment: @XiaHer you should look up your database's documentation.

Comment: Looked at the demo, and went through all the postgres options on there. It should work. I wonder if it's actually Postgres 8.4 or 9.4.

Comment: @XiaHer Try this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=404b01047b93e56ada8af1be7f7c81f7

Comment: How do I look up the database documentation? Developer tools in Chrome?

Comment: @XiaHer I can't tell you which documentation to look up. You must identify your database engine and find it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for York Solutions, they check to make sure you didn't cheat by using forums and such. Just an FYI!